# Multiple commands produce path related to info plist error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, info.plist

I'm confused here. This is the current error message I am looking at:

> Multiple commands produce
>
> '/Users/paulsen_joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWAY-bxwhpscrelfqrzbaxbloulpybaoo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SWAY.app/Info.plist':
>
> 1) Target 'SWAY' (project 'SWAY') has copy command from
>   '/Users/paulsen_joshua/Desktop/sway/SWAY-BASE/Info.plist' to
>   '/Users/paulsen_joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWAY-bxwhpscrelfqrzbaxbloulpybaoo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SWAY.app/Info.plist'
>
> 2) Target 'SWAY' (project 'SWAY') has process command with output
>   '/Users/paulsen_joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWAY-bxwhpscrelfqrzbaxbloulpybaoo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SWAY.app/Info.plist'

What's a starting point to debugging here? I haven't tried anything yet. I wanted to see what SO would say. Feel free to edit the question how you see fit.

Answer (score 8):

I had to `Open target` -> `Build phases` > `Copy Bundle Resources` and remove info.plist from there.

Answer (score 2):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31y40.png)

I modified the file name of info.plist, the problem is solved.
(after modified info.plist file name, you must specify plist file in the General menu)

Comment: Nice fix! Thank you for sharing, we switched our build settings to (Legacy) and that seemed to fix it for now... Going to not accept this as the answer and leave this question open so other people can post solutions they found!

Comment: @JIOSH Switch build system may not be the ultimate solution, because apple worked hard to come up with a new build system that we'd better to use it. But that's just a personal observation : )

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem by removing the file (in my case it was "GoogleService-Info.plist") from the supporting folder and deleted the refrences for it